# Fire an event when .load() is ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I load an other HTML page to this one and when it's ready I want to change the css of an element from that page. The problem is that the "changing" function triggers before the other page is loaded. So it does nothing.

```
$("#navbar").load("/other.html");


$("#otherPageElem").css({
   "background": "black",
   "color": "white"
});
```

Comment: See the [jQuery .load() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/). It clearly shows a complete callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the complete callback of [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$("#navbar").load("/other.html", function(){
  // new html exists now

    $("#otherPageElem").css({
       "background": "black",
       "color": "white"
    });

});
```